# Question regarding a proof that: If $X, Y$ are ordinals, and $X\neq Y$, one is an Initial Segment of the other

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation

The proof states that if $X\subset Y$ or $Y\subset X$ then done.

So assume otherwise: then $X\cap Y\subset X$ and $X\cap Y\subset Y$.

It then establishes a contradiction, dispelling this assumption to complete the proof.

**My question** is even if $X\subset Y$ or $Y\subset X$, wouldn't $X\cap Y\subset X$ and $X\cap Y\subset Y$ still be true. So how does it's negation establish the proof?

Thanks

**EDIT** As Prof. Caicedo suggests, here is the balance of the proof:

$X\cap Y$ is an ordinal (proved earlier) so $X\cap Y=X_a$ (an initial segment) and $X\cap Y=Y_b$. Then $a=X_a=X\cap Y=Y_b=b$.

But $a\in X,b\in Y$. Thus $a=b\in X\cap Y$. But $X\cap Y=X_a$, so

$x\in X\cap Y\rightarrow x\lt a$. In particular, $a\lt a$, a contradiction.

Comment: $X\cap Y$ is always a subset of $X$ and $Y$. The proof establishes a contradiction from the assumption that neither $X$ nor $Y$ is a subset of the other. Along the way, the argument may make use of the fact that $X\cap Y$ is a subset of both $X$ and $Y$, but of course we cannot tell since you did not provide enough details of how the proof goes to check this.

Comment: For instance, do you understand why if $X,Y$ are ordinals and $X\subset Y$ then $X$ is an initial segment of $Y$?

Comment: OK, so the point is that $X\cap Y\ne X$ (or else $X=X\cap Y\subset Y$), so it is a *proper* subset of $X$ (which is the reason why $a$ exists). Similarly, $X\cap Y\ne Y$ (or else $Y\subset X$), so it is a proper subset of $Y$ (which is why $b$ exists). Does this clarify the argument?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Yes, thanks. I was just writing: I think the proof is that $X_a\neq Y_b$ for any $a,b$, so as you suggested earlier, neither is a subset of the other?

Comment: Obviously $X_a=Y_b$ since both sets are equal to $X\cap Y$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I thought that was dispelled by the contradiction (hopeless). However, I do see (and always appreciate) your point. With regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see. We already know that if $A,B$ are ordinals then so is $A\cap B$. Also, an initial segment of $A$ is either $A$ itself or else it has the form $A_a:=\{ x\in A:x<a\}$ for some $a\in A$. We also already have that, in that case,  $A_a=a$. And we also have that if $A\subseteq B$ then $A$ is an initial segment of $B$.

The problem is to check that if $X,Y$ are ordinals and $X\ne Y$ then one of them is a proper initial segment of the other.

The proof is by contradiction. Hence, assume $X\nsubseteq Y$ and $Y\nsubseteq X$. Consider $X\cap Y$ and note that $X\cap Y\ne X$: otherwise, $X=X\cap Y\subseteq Y$ and therefore $X$ is after all an initial segment of $Y$. Since $X\cap Y$ is an ordinal and $X\cap Y\subseteq X$, then it is an initial segment of $X$ (and in fact a proper initial segment, since $X\cap Y\ne X$). Thus there is an $x\in X$ with $x=X_x=X\cap Y$.

The same argument, reversing the roles of $X$ and $Y$, shows that $X\cap Y$ is a proper initial segment of $Y$, so there is a $y\in Y$ with $y=Y_y=X\cap Y$.

Now we have reached a contradiction: We have $x=X\cap Y=y$. This means that $x=y$ is in both $X$ and $Y$ and therefore it is in $X\cap Y$. But no ordinal belongs to itself.